# Compute mean of HDF5 dataset to use in caffe classification

Tags: c++, neural-network, caffe

I use `classification.cpp` to classify my images based on a trained network in caffe neural network toolbox.
This file has some arguments as follows:

```
1-model_file
2-trained_file
3-mean_file
4-label_file
5-test_file
```

`mean_file` is computed by `caffe-master/build/tools/compute_image_mean`.

Now I created a `HDF5` dataset and trained a net. So I have 1,2,4,5 arguments but I don't know how can I compute `mean_file`. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Currently mean_file is computed using compute_image_mean from a LEVELDB or LMDB database, and HDF5 is not supported. You can compute the mean using python script since hdf5 is quite friendly to python, and then save it to .binaryproto file.

A more simple way is that you can modify the classification.cpp and subtract the (104,117,124) mean_value, which is supposed to be same as the mean_value in your model prototxt file. For example, you can add a function like:

```
void Classifier::SetMean(const vector<float> &mean_values) {
   cv::Scalar channel_mean(0);
   double *ptr = &channel_mean[0];
   for (int i = 0; i < num_channels_; ++i) {
       ptr[i] = mean_values[i];
   }
   mean_ = cv::Mat(input_geometry_, (num_channels_ == 3 ? CV_32FC3 : CV_32FC1),channel_mean);
}
```

Then you can set mean with vector mean_values (104,117,124).

Comment: Thanks, in second part of your comment, can you explain more? (because I use caffe in c++ code)

Comment: I have edited the answer, and hope it would be helpful.